Server Load from Uptime Checks
I use GCP uptime check to monitor my website checking the home page response is OK.
These uptime checks create a significant server load.  With 1 min interval uptime checks the CPU use of my VM goes up by around 8% per website.
Can anyone suggest a more efficient way of performing uptime checks ? I use WordPress and I am considering maybe making a webpage that does not use WordPress and just loads some HTML.

Google Cloud monitoring uptime checks make simple HTTP/HTTPS/TCP requests, by default from 6 different locations, and you configured the frequency to be 1 min. This means 6 requests per minute. That shouldn't generate a load your server can't handle. However, if you want to reduce the load, there are a few options for starters:

Reduce frequency e.g. to 15 mins.
Reduce number of sources from 6 to the minimum 3.
Use TCP instead of HTTP/HTTPS, assuming this is sufficient for you.

If you use HTTP/HTTPS uptime checks, please note these will follow redirects automatically. Perhaps you have some sort of misconfiguration around redirects on your server.

Thats very helpful thanks.  My server VM is just E2 2vCPU, one site had a psswd protect page, I only have object caching, plus the checks from 6 sources do make it worse.

To answer my own question my E2 Med GCP VM Server with 2 Wordpress / Woocommerce sites was struggling because I had not set up caching correctly.
Using the Wordpress Fastest Cache plugin makes uptime checks unnoticeable on my site.
The most significant improvement for speeding up wordpress / woocommerce came from PHP caching.  Use the WP OPcache plugin to see what opcache is doing and then change the settings.  This gave me something like a 4 times speed & server load improvement.
Redis Caching is also good and changing Apache from MPM Prefork to Event helps with Wordpress.
All of these things are easy to do after some googling and my 2 Wordpress sites on a £20 a month GCP VM server are now fast and with much lower cpu use.


making a webpage that does not use wordpress and just loads some HTML

That makes sense. You can even use web-server status page for this (e.g. Apache's mod_status, Nginx's ngx_http_status_module, etc.), which will not just indicate the server aliveness, but also will show some statistics you can parse and extract metrics in your monitoring; I don't know whether it's possible to make use of this in GCP uptime check.
But, it would check that the web server is alive, not that the application you really need works. What is the value of a check that shows "ok" because web server is alive, when application throws 500 because the database isn't available? To perform the ultimate check, you need to mimic an end-user behavior as much as you can; that means, the check should do the same thing that user would be doing. Users would load pages from your application (e.g. Wordpress) rather than synthetic status page or other "aliveness check" URL.
You can try to balance these two approaches: do lightweight "static page" check every minute (to reduce load) and do heavy "full application" checks say, every 15 minutes to catch tricky "partial failures".
Is your Wordpress cached? Caching might be better solution to reduce load not from just monitoring, but also from real user usage too.

If "just loads some html" is sufficient, then just pull back some static content.....because you already configured your webserver so that requests for static content bypassed the Wordpress front-controller, didn't you?

@symcbean Are you sure this comment belongs to an answer? Why are you asking me about the web server configuration? I don't know how O.P. configured it.

Question was directed at OP. But only makes sense in the context of your answer.

Yes thanks this would only test apache.  I think when my Wordpress has had a fatal error previously it ran out of memory and OOM killed maria DB.  My knowledge of Wordpress errors is limited so probably safest to use my homepage and 5 min checks from 3 locations.  I use REDIS but am mistrusting of Wordpress caching plugins which I dont need anyway.
